# How to judge a phrase is a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> The families of the MH370 passengers in Kuala Lumpur huddled in
>   conference rooms at a hotel. Selamat Omar, a 60-year-old Malaysian 
>   whose son was on the missing aircraft, prepared himself for
>   bad news. "I am sad, but as a Muslim I accept what has
>   happened," he said as he waited for news of his 29-year-old
>   son, Mohamad Khirul Amri, a passenger employed  by a private jet
>   company as an engineer . He was traveling to Beijing to ***work on***
>   an aircraft in need of repair.

How to judge "work on " as a phrasal verb or a verb plus a preposition?

Answer (score 4):

In contemporary grammar the term *phrasal verb* has two somewhat different meanings.

1. In one meaning the term names any *idiomatic* combination of a verb and a preposition or locative/directive adverb whose meaning cannot be understood from the ordinary senses of the words involved.

   Under this meaning, *work on* would be called a ‘phrasal verb’ here, because *on an aircraft* does not have its ordinary sense of telling you where Mohamad Khirul Amri was to work. It tells you what object is affected by his work, just as if *work on* were an ordinary transitive verb:

   > He repaired the aircraft.
   >   He flew the aircraft.
   >   He worked on the aircraft.

   This meaning is current mostly among teachers of English as a foreign/second language (and is not used by all of them).
2. The other meaning restricts the term to combinations of a verb and a ‘particle’—again, a preposition or locative/directive adverb—with specific syntactic characteristics:

   - The particle can be moved after a very ‘light’ (short) direct object, and *must* be moved after a pronoun:

     > <sup>ok</sup>She worked up a detailed presentation.
     >   <sup>ok</sup>She worked up the presentation. *OR* <sup>ok</sup>She worked the presentation up.
     >   <sup>ok</sup>She worked it up. *BUT NOT*  <sup>∗</sup>She worked up it.
   - The particle cannot be ‘pied-piped’ with *wh-* relatives to the front of a clause:

     > <sup>ok</sup>This is the presentation which she worked up. *BUT NOT*
     >    <sup>∗</sup>This is the presentation up which she worked.

   Under this meaning, *work on* would **not** be called a ‘phrasal verb’ here, because *on* does not have this movement pattern:

   > <sup>∗</sup>He was traveling to Beijing to work it on.
   >   <sup>ok</sup>This is the aircraft on which he was to work.

   This meaning is the one used by most general linguists. An equivalent term is *particle verb*.

So the answer really depends on how your teacher uses the term *phrasal verb*.

Answer (score 1):

Section "I. Definition of the Phrasal Verb and Similar Concepts" answers your question, but do read [the entire page](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6361lamont.html#Early%20Modern). All bolds are mine:

---

A phrasal verb in Present-Day English is a verb that takes a complementary particle, in other words, an adverb resembling a preposition, necessary to complete a sentence. A common example is the verb “to fix up”: “He fixed up the car.” The word “up” here is a particle, not a preposition, because “up” can move: “He fixed the car up.” This movement of the particle “up” quickly distinguishes it from the preposition “up”.

**Because the forms of the particle and the preposition are themselves identical, it is easy to confuse phrasal verbs with a very similar-looking type of verb: the prepositional verb.** A prepositional verb takes a complementary prepositional phrase. Movement verbs are readily identifiable examples. For example, the verb “to go” is intransitive, and without the benefit of context, it cannot operate in a complete sentence only accompanied by a subject. One cannot say, “I went,” and expect to satisfy a listener without including a prepositional phrase of place, such as “I went to the store.”

**Prepositional verbs are immediately distinguishable from phrasal verbs in terms of movement**, as prepositions cannot move after their objects. It is not possible to say, “I went the store to,” and so “went” is a prepositional verb. **There are, in fact, several syntactic tests to distinguish phrasal from prepositional verbs, and these will be discussed in detail in the final section.** It is also necessary to understand that the term “verb phrase” refers not to phrasal verbs, but more generally to a sentence verb, its complements, and matters of tense, aspect, mood, voice and so on.

Answer (score 0):

'To work on' is different in meaning to 'to work'. So, in this case, I would say that is a phrasal verb.